# Finding a limit on multiple square roots in a row?

Tags: calculus, limits

Here are basically my two problems, which I have the answer from WolframAlpha:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\sqrt 2-\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2})=1-\sqrt 2
$$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt n-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2})=0
$$

I have no idea how to actually solve them on my own though. At this moment it's gonna be inf - inf (and inf - 2 inf + inf for the second one) which I can't do nothing with (am I remembering correctly that you can't subtract infinity from infinity?). I need to simplify them somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}=\frac{(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1})}{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}=\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}
$$ and similarly
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n+2}&=(\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n+1})+(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})\\\\&=-\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}.
\end{align}
$$

Then let $n \to \infty$ to conclude.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exaclty what I was looking for.

Comment: @PadaKatel You are welcome.